# Remote Apache Tomcat Configuration on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, postgresql, apache, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'M Using DigitalOcean Server with Debian 9, in this server, I installed Apache tomcat, JVM, PostgreSQL

I developed one project on my own machine (Macbook Air) and it is run on the IntelliJ Idea,

I just want to try it by using Remote Debian 9 Server. not on my own machine.

Remote machine is allows to using SFTP, i added it and tested so connection is okay. But Apache Tomcat Configuration is not.

Apache Tomcat Error:
https://ibb.co/60nPLyf

SFTP Configuration:
https://ibb.co/G7kBT53

SFTP Test is Okay:
https://ibb.co/j4mmvHQ

And also same thing is happens to Remote PostgreSQL connection,

Default user, database and I'm sure for password because i changed it, Again it says failed.

PostgreSQL error case : https://ibb.co/Fskr1mR

Comment: In remote [Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html#2742d022) you need to add Tomcat server - this is the local server you have installed on your local machine. The server must be of the same version as the remote server. See the description of remote tomect configuration in the given link.

Comment: Actually my situation is reverse of your comment but thanks in anyway cause, i installed tomcat to remote server but not to my local machine, so problem should be it is. i'll try this and edit this comment, thank you so much.

Comment: Edit: Yes this is the problem Server side Tomcat is 9.0.14 and local 9.0.16 but doesn't matter if both of them is 9.x.x is okay, and app server is worked thank you so much.